# How to use VersionControlEx in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, vs-extensibility

I have a Visual Studio 2013 extension that has a reference to  [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.teamfoundation.versioncontrol(v=vs.120).aspx), from which the following type can be obtained:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlEx
```

Today I uninstalled all previous installations of Visual Studio and then installed Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise with the options ".NET desktop development" and "Visual Studio extension development".

I opened the project with Visual Studio 2017 and had to replace some of the references (EnvDTE, envdte80, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15, etc) and also installed the nuget package [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.All](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.All).

Unfortunately the namespace `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation` and therefore `VersionControlEx` are not recognized.

I have searched the file on my machine with [FileLocator Lite](https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite) and it does not exist.

Any idea how has this changed in Visual Studio 2017?

I basically to access the PendingChanges window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By doing a search, I was able to find the file in there:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
```

I also found copies associated with other versions of Visual Studio. Given the path of the file, it appears to be included along with Team Explorer.

I suspect the reason you were not able to find the file on your machine is that you had uninstalled your prior versions of Visual Studio and Visual Studio 2017 did not release with Team Explorer.
If you [update your version of Visual Studio or you run the standalone installer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/04/05/team-explorer-for-tfs-2017/), I expect that you will be able to find the file.

Comment: Looks like the problem was exactly that Team Explorer was not release. I uninstalled all visual studios and then used the latest installer from MSDN downloads and it works fine now.